# How to make a password checker in Lua

Tags: lua, passwords

```
local pass = io.read()

local letters = {"A","a","B","b","C","c","D","d","E","e","F","f","G","g","H","h","I","i","J","j","K","k","L","l","M","m","N","n","O","o","P","p","Q","q","R","r","S","s","T","t","U","u","V","v","W","w","X","x","Y","y","Z","z"}
local numbers = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"}
local symbols = {">","!","&","+","$","#","é"}

if pass == letters then
    print("weak password")

elseif pass == letters and numbers then

    print ("mid password")

elseif pass == letters and numbers and symbols then

    print ("stong password!!")

end
```

When I run the code it works but it doesn't respond as weak password or mid password or strong password

Comment: Seems you might have a fundamental misunderstanding of what `==` will do for you verses what you need to do for it to use it properly with a table. `pass` will be a string, you can not blindly check if that string is equal to `letters` which is a table as that does not make any sense the 2 will never be equal. furthermore `pass == letters and numbers and symbols` will not check if pass is equal to letters and numbers and symbols, it will simply check if pass is equal to letter and then if numbers and symbols are "true".

Comment: You need to work on the basic, I suggest reading [Programing in Lua](https://lua.org/pil/contents.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparisons are all completely wrong.

- `pass == letters`: This compares the read password string to the table `letters`. Values of different types are never equal in Lua. Even if the array was "stringified" as in JS this would still not correctly capture the intention (you're not trying to check against the sorted alphabet)
- `pass == letters and numbers`: This contains the same mistake plus a second one: `numbers` is a table and thus always truthy. This is equivalent to `pass == letters and true` which is just `pass == letters`.
- `pass == letters and numbers and symbols` again repeats the mistake and is thus equivalent to `pass == letters` which is still always `false`.

Instead of comparing, you may use *pattern matching* to determine whether the password matches your criteria:

```lua
local pass = io.read()
if pass:match"[A-Za-z]*" then -- password consists only of letters; may be empty
    print("weak password")
elseif not pass:match"[^A-Za-z0-9]" then -- password contains no characters except letters and numbers => password consists of letters and numbers
    print("mid password")
elseif pass:match"[A-Za-z]" and pass:match"[0-9]" and (pass:match"[>!&+$#]" or pass:match"é") then
    -- password contains at least one letter, one digit and a symbol; é is represented as two characters in UTF-8 and must thus be treated specially
    print("strong password!!")
end -- else-branch is left as an exercise to the reader
```

You might want to use the character classes `%a` and `%d` here. Keep in mind that these may be locale specific, treating `é` for instance as a letter rather than a symbol.

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling with tables and my friend told me to do a password checker this is why I was made some interesting mistakes. Thanks again